# Show only Post titles with thumbnails in category pages

Tags: wordpress, categories

In my category page full post are showing up. I want to make it only post titles with tumbnails. I'm using wordpress Twenty twelve theme.

Answer (score 1):

Keep 
`<?php the_title(); ?>` and `<?php the_thumbnail(); ?>`. Remove either `<?php the_content(); ?>` or `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`, dependant on which you have.